# Help with a proof from Brezis' book Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand this proof from Brezis, "Functional Analysis,Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations".

[image]

Two points are not clear to me:

1. Why is true that $\lambda_n\to \|x\|$? Does it come from the weak convergence?
2. Why is it stated that $\|y\|\le\liminf \|(y_n +y)/2\|$? By weak convergence one should have $\|y\|\le\liminf\|y_n\|$ (as stated also in the mentioned Proposition 3.5 (iii)).

Anyone could clarify these two points please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using the assumption, we have $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| \leq \|x\| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\|$$
   hence $\limsup \|x_n\| = \liminf \|x_n\| = \|x\|$, meaning that $(\|x_n\|)_n$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| = \|x\|$. With this, it is somewhat clear that $(\max(\|x_n\|, \|x\|))_n = (\lambda_n)_n$ also converges to $\|x\|$ (left as an exercise).
2. You want to use that Proposition on the sequence $((y_n + y)/2)_n$ which also weakly converges to $y$ since $(y)_n$ converges to $y$.

Comment: Bruno B, reading again your answer I find something not clear at point 1. You have proved that $x_n\to x$ strongly? This is the final claim of the theorem, how can you deduce that at point 1.?

Comment: @Physicsuser Where did Bruno say something that implies $\|x_n - x\| \to 0$ in response to (1)?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think I got it. In point 1., Bruno says that the sequence of norms $(\|x_n\|)_n$ converges to $\|x\|$. But this fact does not imply that $x_n\to x$ strongly, right?

Comment: @Physicsuser Yes.  In other words, the triangle inequality shows $$| \|x_n\| - \|x\| | \leq \|x_n - x\|$$ but showing that the smaller value tends to $0$ tells us nothing about the upper bound.